# Call drupal_add_js and drupal_add_library in ctools modal callback

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I am trying to load yandex.maps on ctools modal, and i need to pass map settings to js and load yandex.api js libraries inside modal. But somehow drupal_add_js and drupal_add_library doesn't work inside ctools modal callback. How can make them work inside my callback? Here is my testing code:

```
function carroza_user_page_show_map($carroza_user, $js = NULL) {    
  if (!$js) {
    drupal_access_denied();
  }

  ctools_include('modal');
  ctools_include('ajax');

  $carroza_user = carroza_user_load($carroza_user->carroza_uid);

  $id = 'ymap-carroza-user';
  $coords = $carroza_user->field_yamap['und'][0]['coords'];
  $type = $carroza_user->field_yamap['und'][0]['type'];
  $placemarks = $carroza_user->field_yamap['und'][0]['placemarks'];
  $lines = $carroza_user->field_yamap['und'][0]['lines'];
  $polygons = $carroza_user->field_yamap['und'][0]['polygons'];
  $routes = $carroza_user->field_yamap['und'][0]['routes'];

  $coords = drupal_json_decode($coords);

  $map = array(
    'init' => array(
      'center' => $coords['center'],
      'zoom' => $coords['zoom'],
      'type' => $type,
      'behaviors' => array('scrollZoom', 'dblClickZoom', 'drag'),
    ),
    'controls' => TRUE,
    'traffic' => TRUE,
    'placemarks' => drupal_json_decode($placemarks),
    'lines' => drupal_json_decode($lines),
    'polygons' => drupal_json_decode($polygons),
    'routes' => drupal_json_decode($routes),
    'edit' => FALSE,
  );

  //These lines are not being called
  drupal_add_js(array('yamaps' => array($id => $map)), 'setting');
  drupal_add_library('yamaps', 'yamaps.full');

  $output = '<div id="'. $id .'" style="width:100%;height:350px">&nbsp;</div>';
  $commands[] = ctools_modal_command_display(t('Карта проезда'), $output);
  print ajax_render($commands);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Comment: I *guess* that it's because modal window is opened inside normal page, rendered already, so the head section with `$variables` is already printed and cannot be changed.

Comment: Are there any suggestions that i can call them there?

Comment: If I knew, I would post an answer. I hope my comment will guide someone.